# How can I create a list of tuples representing a deck of cards?

Tags: python, list, tuples, playing-cards

I am trying to make a deck of playing cards,where each is a tuple. For example, the card 'Ace of Hearts' with value of 11 would be `(‘A’, ‘♥’, 11)`. 
How can I generate the entire deck without using classes and save it in a list?

Comment: A standard card deck is pretty much just a [Cartesian product of the ranks and suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#A_deck_of_cards). One list comprehension could do it. How you define the "value" might be more interesting; it may be simply a function of the rank.

Comment: I'm sure you could, have you tried?

Comment: I’m voting to close this for being too vague/broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using static definitions for the suits, cards, and values, you can do the following to get a list of cards using a list comprehension - the deck list then contains tuples representing cards. You may want to change how the values list is defined according to your requirements.

```
suits = ['♠', '♥', '♦', '♣']
cards = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
values = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]


deck = [(c, s, v) for c, v in zip(cards, values) for s in suits]
```

Comment: thank you very much! and if i want to give specific values to a specific card number ? do i have to make a new list of tuples? for example how can i make the value of card Ace of Hearts to be 11?

Comment: This is where classes would be a better approach! You'd need to find the card in `deck` that represents the ace of hearts and change the value. Note that in the current implementation, the value is already `11`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `collections.namedtuple`, but I do think classes (especially `Enum.enum`s are the way to go here):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Card = namedtuple("Card", ["rank", "suit"])

cards = []
for suit in "\u2660", "\u2665", "\u2666", "\u2663":
    for rank in "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K":
        cards.append(Card(rank, suit))

print(cards)
```